# How can I split my data into 3 second intervals

Tags: r

I have a large data set and want to split it up based on 3 second intervals and then calculate the mean of each interval and then remove all points within each interval that are more than 2 standard deviations away from the mean  of that interval and then recalculate the mean for each intterval once those points are removed.

```r
interval_size <- 3  

x3$interval <- cut(x3$ts.p, breaks = seq(min(x3$ts.p), max(x3$ts.p) + interval_size, by = interval_size))
```

as my data frame is `x3` and my name for time is `ts.p`.

This however only put a number on to each row of data which increased by 3 each time and did not assign them to an interval based on their time stamp

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What's in `x3$ts.p`? Is it just a count of the number of seconds?

Comment: The `findInterval` function may be useful here. Here is an example of a case using a Date object stackoverflow.com/a/74251758/8806649 –

Answer (score 1):

If input timestamps are date-time values, we could use periods like `3 secs` with `lubridate::floor_date()`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
x3 <- tibble(ts.p = seq(as.POSIXct("2023-01-01 01:02:03"), 
                        units = "seconds", by = .6, length.out = 15))
x3 <- x3 |> mutate(
  s_ms = format(ts.p, "%H:%M:%OS3"),
  int = lubridate::floor_date(ts.p, "3 secs") |> as.numeric())
x3 %>% str()
#> tibble [15 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ ts.p: POSIXct[1:15], format: "2023-01-01 01:02:03" "2023-01-01 01:02:03" ...
#>  $ s_ms: chr [1:15] "01:02:03.000" "01:02:03.599" "01:02:04.200" "01:02:04.799" ...
#>  $ int : num [1:15] 1.67e+09 1.67e+09 1.67e+09 1.67e+09 1.67e+09 ...

split(x3, ~int)
#> $`1672527723`
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   ts.p                s_ms                int
#>   <dttm>              <chr>             <dbl>
#> 1 2023-01-01 01:02:03 01:02:03.000 1672527723
#> 2 2023-01-01 01:02:03 01:02:03.599 1672527723
#> 3 2023-01-01 01:02:04 01:02:04.200 1672527723
#> 4 2023-01-01 01:02:04 01:02:04.799 1672527723
#> 5 2023-01-01 01:02:05 01:02:05.400 1672527723
#> 
#> $`1672527726`
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   ts.p                s_ms                int
#>   <dttm>              <chr>             <dbl>
#> 1 2023-01-01 01:02:06 01:02:06.000 1672527726
#> 2 2023-01-01 01:02:06 01:02:06.599 1672527726
#> 3 2023-01-01 01:02:07 01:02:07.200 1672527726
#> 4 2023-01-01 01:02:07 01:02:07.799 1672527726
#> 5 2023-01-01 01:02:08 01:02:08.400 1672527726
#> 
#> $`1672527729`
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   ts.p                s_ms                int
#>   <dttm>              <chr>             <dbl>
#> 1 2023-01-01 01:02:09 01:02:09.000 1672527729
#> 2 2023-01-01 01:02:09 01:02:09.599 1672527729
#> 3 2023-01-01 01:02:10 01:02:10.200 1672527729
#> 4 2023-01-01 01:02:10 01:02:10.799 1672527729
#> 5 2023-01-01 01:02:11 01:02:11.400 1672527729
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>